# curl version on Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: php, curl

I'm going to invoke curl request with php5.6.
At the moment, curl_init() function gives me "call undefined function" error.
I think curl is not installed for php5.6.
Am I wrong? If not, how can I install php5-curl with Ubuntu17.10?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using [Ondřej Surý's PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/), you need to install `php5.6-curl`.

Comment: Yes, it was actually. I missed the php version at the end . Thank you so much!

Comment: Please accept the answer if it answers your question.

Comment: Thank you, fkraiem. I would love to accept your answer, but I don't know how to do that. Could you tell me?